# Extract TWRP backups made with adb

Tags: adb, backup, linux, twrp

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 GT-I9100 smartphone with LineageOS and TWRP. Every week I make a backup with the following command:

```
adb backup -f twrp-20170322.ab --twrp boot data system
```

I may optionally use the `--compress` option, too.

Is there a way to extract the `twrp-20170322.ab` backup file with stardard GNU/Linux command line tools? I will also consider installing extra software if needed, but it must be free (as in freedom).

Links:

- https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/extract-backup-adb-twrp-option-t3577903
- https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/issues/898

Answer (score 2):

I have found that TWRP-generated `.ab` files are different from the normal `adb backup` files, so the offset is different from normal `.ab` files. I was able to inspect and extract files using (for example to inspect) the following command:

```
dd if=backup.ab bs=512 skip=1 | tar ft -
```

Apparently, the header may be longer, but it should be aligned with 512-bytes boundaries, so just bump the `skip=` parameter if it can't find it at first.

Note that the file format is defined in [twadbstream.h](https://github.com/omnirom/android_bootable_recovery/blob/android-7.1/adbbu/twadbstream.h), if you need to dig into this further.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the naive dd-based approach is that there is metadata every so often in the file. This results in corruption for files of any significant length.

I wrote an extraction tool utilizing twadbstream.h (thanks @anarcat) that I have used to successfully recover large (~10GB) multi-filesystem TWRP ADB backups.
[twrpabx](https://github.com/arifogel/twrpabx)

Comment: Thank you! Your tool worked for me after applying these patches mentioned in the Github issues https://github.com/prudy/twrpabx/tree/img_and_issue4

Comment: @TrojanName were you able to extract multi partitions backup with these patches?

Comment: @SandroAntonucci Yes I think it did

Answer (score 1):

Provided you didn't protect it with a password:

```
dd if=$1 bs=24 skip=1 | openssl zlib -d >${1%%.ab}.tar
```

- `dd` is the "Disk Duplicator" (also known as "disk destroyer" in case you confuse its parameters ans switch `if` and `of` ;)
- `bs=23` advises it to use a block size of 24 byte, which we need to…
- `skip=1` skip 1 block of 24 byte (the "Backup header")
- the output gets piped to `openssl` to process and unpack it
- … and the output from that is redirected to a Tarball

From there, you should know your way: simply "untar" (extract) what you want.

Why it uses `$1`? Well, I copied this line from [`ab2tar`](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar/blob/master/tools/ab2tar), which is included with my little tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) you might be interested in as well: creates a nice device documentation, backup scripts and more, all via ADB using nothing but Bash  So put that line in a tiny little shell script, and call it:

```
ab2tar twrp-20170322.ab
```

Then find a `twrp-20170322.tar` as result. Of course, this requires `openssl` to be installed on your Linux machine.

Comment: I get the following error message: 140376894071512:error:29065064:lib(41):BIO_ZLIB_READ:zlib inflate error:c_zlib.c:548:zlib error:data error

Comment: Never seen that. Could it be TWRP uses a different compression method than standard ADB (I couldn't find details on that)? Or, as you didn't specify `--compress` when creating the backup, creates uncompressed backups? In the latter case, try leaving out the `zlib` parameter (or do it the other way around and specify `--compress` when creating the backup ;).

Comment: I tried with: dd if=twrp-20170320.ab bs=24 skip=1 > twrp-20170320.tar (without inserting `openssl`). But when I try to list the contents of the tar archive with tar -tf twrp-20170320.tar I get: tar: This does not look like a tar archive; tar: Skipping to next header; tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: There's a reason for not using the `--compress` option with `adb`: it compresses way less efficiently than `xz`. I prefer to save as much space as possible. But that's not related to my initial problem.

Comment: What I described above works fine for "normal" ADB backups (I use it frequently for those, and I don't use a `--compress` there either). From your statement (`adb backup …`) I assumed the very same format. If you're just using a different compression, you must consider that. `openssl` is needed to decrypt the backup – so without that, you don't get a valid `.tar`. From your last comments, I'd assume you should replace `zlib` by the corresponding part for `xz`. Apart from that, I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: from what i can tell, this procedure only works with "normal" (ie. non-TWRP) generated backups. when TWRP sends the stream, it slaps a new header on top, which is longer (512 bytes). see https://android.stackexchange.com/a/180402/158769 for a solution that worked for me.

Comment: @anarcat Thanks for the pointer! So my approach is still valid, one just has to skip a different sector size – and can skip the entire openssl stuff?

Comment: @Izzy your answer is for adb backup, not working for TWRP backup. check my script [twab.sh](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=81905363&postcount=7)

Comment: Umpf, so are you saying `adb backup` is not creating an "ADB backup" here? That's quite confusing.

Comment: it's `data.ext4.win` with a 1536 bytes header, but 'broken' into datablocks. also it may contain multiple partitions https://sourceforge.net/p/adbextractor/discussion/general/thread/f96e7701/#0a6a